# Подключение содержимого вкладки с помощью ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

У меня на сайте есть страничка, на которой реализована панель вкладок. Работает она при помощи jQuery, но работает так, что содержимое всех вкладок загружается изначально. Мне надо реализовать вот как: содержимое каждой вкладки находится в отдельном файле и подключается, как только я перехожу на вкладку (вся страница при этом не обновляется).

Это легко сделать с помощью ajax, но плюс ко всему мне надо, чтобы при этом менялась ссылка на страницу, т.е., например, панель вкладок на сранице `www.mysite.ru/tabs`, при клике на определенную вкладку ссылка должна принять вид `www.mysite.ru/tabs/tab1.php`. Конечно, это можно сделать с полной перезагрузкой страницы, но хотелось бы с помощью 
ajax.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Совсем забыл, яркий пример тому, что нужно сделать тут: http://vk.com/edit. Только ссылки будут по другому выглядеть.

Comment: там - HTML5 history API

Comment: Как это применить? Есть пример?

Comment: [тут](http://gogle.com) есть все!

Comment: Действительно, зачем нужен http://hashcode.ru, когда есть гугл? люди тут гениальны, пожалуй больше не обращусь.

Comment: Вы верно подметили, на ХК это тоже уже 100500 раз обсуждалось.

Не рановато вы о ресурсе судите?.. Я как-бы тут не один, подождите, быть-может кто-то и погуглит за вас